# Pytest basic example fails with config error

Tags: python, pytest

I've created the basic example described here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html

but when I type `pytest` I obtain

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 206, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config._do_configure()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 639, in _do_configure
INTERNALERROR>     self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 306, in call_historic
INTERNALERROR>     res = self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 67, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 61, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_benchmark/plugin.py", line 427, in pytest_configure
INTERNALERROR>     bs = config._benchmarksession = BenchmarkSession(config)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_benchmark/session.py", line 31, in __init__
INTERNALERROR>     self.logger = Logger(self.verbose, config)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/alberto/Documents/FIREDRAKE/firedrake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_benchmark/logger.py", line 15, in __init__
INTERNALERROR>     self.pytest_warn = config.warn
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'warn'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I had this error when I installed pytest and pytest-benchmark from conda-forge. When I uninstall pytest-benchmark, the error goes away for me. This seems to be https://github.com/ionelmc/pytest-benchmark/issues/147.

Comment: I am not using conda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python3 you can use pip3 to manage your packages. Cause actually, Im getting errors between packages on python2.7 using pip, some packages isn't being updating, so you can choose some safe version to set e.g (pytest==3.9.3). Probably your version installed doesn't have "warn" function inside of that specific class. Actually Im using unittest package to run and build test-cases, you can try this approach If you need speed else fix those dependency issues to run with pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error says that the package can only be used within a git repo. Have you initiated a git repo?

Comment: I get exactly the same error in git repositories. The first line in the error message is there only because I recreated the basic example.

Comment: I have now removed the first line in the error message because it was misleading.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't configure properly. Are you sure that you your version of pytest is compatible with python3.7? You might need an update

Comment: The same error shows up after `pip install pytest --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an incompatibility of the versions of pytest and pytest-benchmark that you have installed. Installing both from pip with `pip install pytest-benchmark` fixed a similar issue for me.